# Scala executing futures differently on server than on dev machine

Tags: multithreading, scala, concurrency, future

I have the following code:

```
private implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2) )

private val done = new AtomicInteger(0)

Future(/* long running task*/).onComplete(_ => done.done.incrementAndGet())

Future(/* second long running task*/).onComplete(_ => done.done.incrementAndGet())


while (done.get() < 2) {
    Thread.sleep(5000)
}
```

(Yes, this is ugly & hacky and doesn't check for errors, etc)

When I run this locally, logs indicate that it ran both futures in parallel, i.e I see logs from both futures at the same time. But when I move this to the server (with fewer CPU cores and memory), I only see logs from one future, indicating that it only ran one of them and presumably it was waiting for that future to finish before running the second one (or was deadlocked somehow).

Any idea why this is? I even increased the fixedThreadCount to 4 but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Firing up `Future` doesn't mean that it will start right away. It might wait until thread from the thread pool is available. Maybe consider using just `new Thread`?

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik But these two futures are running on their own dedicated executor which has two threads.

Comment: Presumably there is some bottleneck somewhere deep inside these tasks. You'll have to find out what that is. Are you sure the second one did not even get started? Is there really no work being done before the first visible log output?

Comment: Are you sure this is not a logging issue? Do you ever see logs from the second `Future`? If so, do the timestamps on the log entries show that the second `Future` does not start until the first finishes?

Comment: @Thilo The second future did get started, but once they get into the main processing (which is blocking), i only see output from the first future and not from the 2nd future.

Comment: @Tim I'm running the same app, on local machine I see logs from both futures but on server I only see them from f1. So I don't think that's a logging issue? I do see preliminary logs from both f1 and f2 (loading config etc) but once they get into the processing, i only see them from f1 which seems to indicate f1 is blocking f2

Comment: If you swap the order of creation, does the same task still dominate, or does the first `Future` always dominate the second whatever code it is running?

Comment: @Tim Well, both tasks are actually running the same code, just passing in different parameters. Its processing the same dataset just slightly differently.

Comment: What happens if you create two separate execution contexts and run each future on its own `ec` respectively?

Comment: The code where I was doing this has been rewritten a lot so I can't test it out anymore unfortunately @MarioGalic - I would guess though that it would run those futures correctly